# Space invaders in java swing

Tags: java, game, mvc, swing

I am not really proud of the final project design. Whenever I try following MVC I get lost and in the end a lot of code doesnt end up where it should be. I am also wondering if am I overusing private members? I am not sure what to do when I have a lot of constants. In this project I declared them in separate classes but is it better to declare them all in one interface or class where they will be public static final? Anyway here's the code, I would be really thankful for review.

```
public class SpaceInvader {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      new SpaceView().runGame();

    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class SpaceView{
    private final Frame frame;
    private final JPanel mainPanel;
    private static GameInfo gameInfo;
    static private BattleArea battleArea;
    public SpaceView()
    {
        frame = new Frame();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        gameInfo = new GameInfo();
        battleArea = new BattleArea();
        setup();
    }
    private void setup()
    {

        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue, 5));
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(gameInfo.getInfoPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(battleArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static BattleArea getBattleArea(){
        return battleArea;
    }
    public static GameInfo getGameInfo(){
        return gameInfo;
    }
    public void runGame(){
        battleArea.startBattle();
    }


}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GameInfo extends JPanel{  //used for showing current score and remaining lives{
    
    private int score = 0;
    private int lives = 5;
    private JLabel scoreLabel;
    private JLabel livesLabel;

    public GameInfo()
    {
        scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + String.valueOf(score));
        setLabelAttributes(scoreLabel);

        livesLabel = new JLabel("Lives: " + String.valueOf(lives));
        setLabelAttributes(livesLabel);

        livesLabel = new JLabel("Lives: " + String.valueOf(lives));
        setLabelAttributes(livesLabel);

        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.blue, 5, 10));
        this.add(scoreLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(livesLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }
    private void setLabelAttributes(JLabel label)  // for easier maintainability in future
    {
        label.setFont(new Font("Font.Galaxus",Font.PLAIN,20));
        label.setForeground(Color.white);
    }
    public JPanel getInfoPanel(){
        return this;
    }
    public void increaseScore(){
        score += 100;
        String newText = "Score: " + score;
        scoreLabel.setText(newText);
    }
    public void loseLife(){
        if (lives == 0) return;
        --lives;
        //same thing like gaining score
        String newText = "Lives: " + lives;
        livesLabel.setText(newText);
    }
    public boolean isOutOfLives(){
        return lives <= 0;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BattleArea extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    private final Guard guard;
    private boolean windowResizeCalledRepaint; //keeps track whether repaint was called by 
     keyPressed() or by resizing window.
    private final ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
    private int delayCounter = 0; //takes care that bullets cant be shoot more than one time in 
    300ms
    private boolean allowedToShoot = false; //true if 200ms passed
    private boolean isRightKeyPressed = false;
    private boolean isLeftKeyPressed = false;
    private boolean isSpaceKeyPressed = false;
    private boolean hasGameStarted = false;
    private final Timer guardBulletMovementTimer;
    private final Timer gameLoopTimer;
    private final Timer hordeMovementTimer;
    private final Timer alienBulletMovementTimer;
    private final AlienHorde alienHorde;

    public BattleArea(){
        alienHorde = new AlienHorde();
        this.setBounds(1,1,1,1);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        guard = new Guard();
        windowResizeCalledRepaint = true;
        bullets = new ArrayList<>();
        guardBulletMovementTimer = new Timer(10, e -> {// moves bullet every 10ms
            moveBullet();
            windowResizeCalledRepaint = false;
            delayCounter += 10;
            if (delayCounter == 500) { // reload time is 300ms
                allowedToShoot = true;
            }
            repaint();
        });
        gameLoopTimer = new Timer(1, e -> {
            moveGuard();
            if(isGuardShot()){
                bullets.removeAll(bullets);
                setGuardAndAlienHordeStartingPosition();
                hasGameStarted = false;
                SpaceView.getGameInfo().loseLife();
            }
            if(isAlienShot()){
                SpaceView.getGameInfo().increaseScore();
            }
            if(SpaceView.getGameInfo().isOutOfLives()){
                stopTimers();
                try {
                    gameOver(false);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
            else if(alienHorde.isDead()){
                stopTimers();
                try {
                    gameOver(true);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }
            }
            repaint();
        });
        hordeMovementTimer = new Timer(25, e->{
            alienHorde.move();
            repaint();
        });
        alienBulletMovementTimer = new Timer(500, e->{
            if(hasGameStarted) {
                bullets.add(alienHorde.randomAlienShot());
            }
        });
    }
    private void stopTimers(){
        gameLoopTimer.stop();
        guardBulletMovementTimer.stop();
        hordeMovementTimer.stop();
        alienBulletMovementTimer.stop();
    }

    private void moveGuard(){
        if(isSpaceKeyPressed){
            if(allowedToShoot){
                bullets.add(guard.shoot());
                allowedToShoot = false;
                delayCounter = 0;
            }
        }
        if(isLeftKeyPressed){
            if(guard.isInLeftBound()){
                guard.setX(guard.getX() - guard.getMovementVelocity());
            }
        }
        if(isRightKeyPressed){
            if(guard.isInRightBound()){
                guard.setX(guard.getX() + guard.getMovementVelocity());
            }
        }
    }
    private void moveBullet(){
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); ++i){
            if(bullets.get(i).getOwner() == Bullet.BulletsOwner.Guard){
                bullets.get(i).setY(bullets.get(i).getY() - bullets.get(i).getVelocity());
                if(bullets.get(i).getY() < 0){
                    bullets.remove(bullets.get(i));
                }
            }
            else if(bullets.get(i).getOwner() == Bullet.BulletsOwner.Alien){
                bullets.get(i).setY(bullets.get(i).getY() + bullets.get(i).getVelocity());
                if(bullets.get(i).getY() > this.getY() + this.getHeight()){
                    bullets.remove(bullets.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void setGuardAndAlienHordeStartingPosition(){

        if(guard.getY() == 0 || windowResizeCalledRepaint){ // we need to set this only one time 
            since we never move on y-axis
            guard.setY(SpaceView.getBattleArea().getY() + 
            SpaceView.getBattleArea().getSize().height - (3 * guard.getWarriorHeight()));
        }
        if(!hasGameStarted){
            alienHorde.setAliensStartingPositions();
            guard.setX(SpaceView.getBattleArea().getX() + (SpaceView.getBattleArea().getSize().width / 2) - (guard.getWarriorWidth() / 2));
        }
        windowResizeCalledRepaint = true;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setGuardAndAlienHordeStartingPosition();
        alienHorde.repaint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g.drawImage(guard.getWarriorImg(), guard.getX(), guard.getY(), null);
        for(Bullet bullet : bullets){
            g.drawImage(bullet.getBulletImg(), bullet.getX(), bullet.getY(), null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        hasGameStarted = true;
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        switch (key){
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                    isSpaceKeyPressed = true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    isLeftKeyPressed = true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    isRightKeyPressed = true;
                break;

        }
        windowResizeCalledRepaint = false;
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        switch (key){
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                    isSpaceKeyPressed = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
              isLeftKeyPressed = false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
               isRightKeyPressed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        public void startTimers(){
            gameLoopTimer.start();
            guardBulletMovementTimer.start();
            hordeMovementTimer.start();
            alienBulletMovementTimer.start();
        }
        public boolean isGuardShot(){
            for (Bullet bullet : bullets){
                if(ColisionHandler.isColision(guard, bullet)){
                    bullets.remove(bullet);
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
        public boolean isAlienShot(){
        var alienHordeList = alienHorde.getAlienHorde();
            for (ArrayList<Alien> aliens : alienHordeList) {
                for (Alien alien : aliens) {
                    for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
                        if (ColisionHandler.isColision(alien, bullet)){
                            bullets.remove(bullet);
                            alien.setImageToNull();
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void startBattle(){
        startTimers();
        }
    private void gameOver(boolean won) throws InterruptedException {
        String message = won ? "You win" : "You lose";
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Font font = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 28);
        FontMetrics ft = this.getFontMetrics(font);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(message, (this.getWidth()-ft.stringWidth(message))/2, this.getHeight()/2);
        while(true){} // we have to stop program somehow because paint methods will overdraw our message.
    }

}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Warrior extends JPanel{
    protected Image warriorImg;
    final protected int warriorWidth;
    final protected int warriorHeight;
    protected final int movementVelocity;
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected Image bulletImg;




    public Warrior(Image warriorImg, int movementVelocity, Image bulletImg){
        this.warriorImg = warriorImg;
        this.movementVelocity = movementVelocity;
        warriorWidth = warriorImg.getWidth(null);
        warriorHeight = warriorImg.getHeight(null);
        y = 0;
        x = 0;
        this.bulletImg = bulletImg;
    }

    public int getMovementVelocity() {
        return movementVelocity;
    }
    public int getWarriorWidth() {
        return warriorWidth;
    }

    public int getWarriorHeight() {
        return warriorHeight;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public Image getWarriorImg() {
        return warriorImg;
    }

    public boolean isInLeftBound(){
        return (x - movementVelocity > SpaceView.getBattleArea().getX());
    }
    public boolean isInRightBound(){
        return (x + movementVelocity < SpaceView.getBattleArea().getX() + SpaceView.getBattleArea().getWidth() - warriorWidth);
    }


}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class AlienHorde {
     private enum Direction{
         RIGHT,
         LEFT
    }
     private final ArrayList<ArrayList<Alien>> alienHorde;
    //horde will be 4x5
     private final int rows = 4;
     private final int columns = 5;
     private Direction direction; // 1 = right -1 = left
     private final Random random;
     public AlienHorde(){
         random = new Random();
         direction = Direction.RIGHT;
         alienHorde = new ArrayList<>(4);
         for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
             alienHorde.add(new ArrayList<Alien>());
             for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
                 alienHorde.get(i).add(new Alien());
             }
         }
     }
     private void moveHordeByOneStep(Direction direction){
         int dir = direction == Direction.RIGHT ? 1 : -1;
         for(var alienLine : alienHorde){
             for (Alien alien : alienLine){
               alien.setX(alien.getX() + dir * alien.getMovementVelocity());
             }
         }
     }
     public void move(){

         for(int i = 0; i < alienHorde.size(); ++i){
             for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
                 if(direction == Direction.RIGHT){
                     if(alienHorde.get(alienHorde.size() - 1).get(alienHorde.get(0).size() - 1).isInRightBound()){
                         moveHordeByOneStep(Direction.RIGHT);
                         break;
                     }
                     else direction = Direction.LEFT;
                 }


                 else if(direction == Direction.LEFT){
                     if(alienHorde.get(0).get(0).isInLeftBound()){
                        moveHordeByOneStep(Direction.LEFT);
                        break;
                     }
                     else direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                 }
             }
         }

     }
     public void setAliensStartingPositions(){
         int timesOfAlienWidth = 6; // this means first alien has distance 7 times his own width from left side of map
         int timesOfAlienHeight = 0; // this means first alien has distance 1 times his own width from top side of map
         for(var alienLine : alienHorde){
             for (Alien alien : alienLine){
                 alien.setX(SpaceView.getBattleArea().getX() + timesOfAlienWidth * alien.getWarriorWidth() );
                 alien.setY(SpaceView.getBattleArea().getY() + timesOfAlienHeight * alien.getWarriorHeight() );
                 timesOfAlienWidth += 2; // next alien goes more right
             }
             timesOfAlienWidth = 6;
             timesOfAlienHeight++; // next row goes more below
         }
     }
     public void repaint(Graphics g){


         for(var alienLine : alienHorde){
             for (Alien alien : alienLine){
                g.drawImage(alien.getWarriorImg(), alien.getX(),alien.getY(), null);
             }
         }
     }
     public Bullet randomAlienShot(){
         int i,j;
         do{
             i = random.nextInt(rows);
             j = random.nextInt(columns);
             if(isDead()) break;
         } while (alienHorde.get(i).get(j).getWarriorImg() == null);

         return alienHorde.get(i).get(j).shoot();
     }
     public ArrayList<ArrayList<Alien>> getAlienHorde(){
         return alienHorde;
     }
     public boolean isDead(){
         for(var alienLine : alienHorde){
             for (Alien alien : alienLine){
                 if(alien.getWarriorImg() != null) return false;
             }
         }
         return true;
     }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Guard extends Warrior{
    public Guard(){
        super(new ImageIcon("Guard.png").getImage(), 3, new ImageIcon("GuardBullet.png").getImage());
        this.bulletImg = this.bulletImg.getScaledInstance(13, 15, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    }
    public Bullet shoot(){
        int middleOfImageOnX = x + (warriorWidth / 2) - 5;  //approximately gets bullet in the middle of guard image, 3 is magic number
        int bulletAboveGuardY = y - bulletImg.getHeight(null);
        return new Bullet(bulletImg, middleOfImageOnX, bulletAboveGuardY, Bullet.BulletsOwner.Guard);
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Bullet {
    public enum BulletsOwner{
        Guard,
        Alien,
    }
    private int velocity;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private final Image bulletImg;
    private final BulletsOwner owner;

    public Bullet(Image bulletImg, int x, int y, BulletsOwner owner){
        this.bulletImg = bulletImg;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.owner = owner;
        velocity = 5;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Image getBulletImg() {
        return bulletImg;
    }

    public BulletsOwner getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public int getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Alien extends Warrior{
    public Alien(){
        super(new ImageIcon("Alien.png").getImage(), 1, new ImageIcon("AlienBullet.png").getImage());
        this.bulletImg = this.bulletImg.getScaledInstance(13, 15, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    }
    public Bullet shoot(){
        int middleOfImageOnX = x + (warriorWidth / 2) - 5;  //approximately gets bullet in the middle of guard image, 3 is magic number
        int bulletAboveGuardY = y - bulletImg.getHeight(null);
        return new Bullet(bulletImg, middleOfImageOnX, bulletAboveGuardY, Bullet.BulletsOwner.Alien);
    }
    public void setImageToNull(){
        warriorImg = null;
    }
}
```

```
public class ColisionHandler {
    public static boolean isColision(Guard guard, Bullet bullet) {
        if (bullet.getOwner() == Bullet.BulletsOwner.Guard) return false;

        return (bullet.getX() >= guard.getX() && bullet.getX() <= guard.getX() + guard.getWarriorWidth()
                && bullet.getY() >= guard.getY() && bullet.getY() <= guard.getY() + guard.getWarriorHeight());
    }
    public static boolean isColision(Alien alien, Bullet bullet) {
        if (bullet.getOwner() == Bullet.BulletsOwner.Alien || alien.getWarriorImg() == null) return false;
        return (bullet.getX() >= alien.getX() && bullet.getX() <= alien.getX() + alien.getWarriorWidth()
                && bullet.getY() >= alien.getY() - alien.getWarriorHeight()
                && bullet.getY() <= alien.getY());
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public Frame(){
       this.setSize(500,500);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
       this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0)); // grid (1,0) so added panel fills whole frame
       this.setTitle("Space invaders");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  It's not runnable since we don't have access to the image files you're using.  1) Don't name classes the same as standard Java classes.  `Frame` is `java.awt.Frame`.  2) You should have one drawing `JPanel`.  Everything else is drawn on that one drawing `JPanel`.  3) You should have only one game loop `Timer`.  Everything happens based on that one timer.  You can skip cycles for objects that are supposed to move slower.  4) All your data should be in the model.  The model consists of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.

Comment: What do you mean by drawing JPanel

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.